# Current day sale with previous sale

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, group-by

My question is to write a query to display the product name with Sale_date,count of product sold on current day, count of product sold on previous day(it could be non-continuous).
My input table is like this-
Product

```
id    Name     Brand

10    Nexus     LG

20     Z2      Sony

30    Alpha   Samsung

40     6S      Apple
```

and 
My sales table is like this-

```
Invoice_No,Product_Id     Sale_Date           Quantity

122300       10     23-11-14 09:00:00 AM      5

122300       20     23-11-14 05:00:00 PM      2

122311       10     24-11-14 10:00:00 AM      1

122312       20     24-11-14 10:05:00 AM      2

122313       10     24-11-14 10:10:00 AM     10

122314       30     24-11-14 12:00:00 PM     10

122315       10     24-11-14 04:00:00 PM      3

122316       40     25-11-14 11:33:00 PM      2

122317       10     29-11-14 03:10:15 PM      5

122318       20     30-11-14 05:06:10 PM     10

122319       10     30-11-14 11:15:06 AM      15

122320       10     01-12-14 12:00:00 PM      10
```

My output table is like this-

Product_id,Sale_Date,CurrentDay_Count,PrevDay_count

```
10      23-11-14    5   
10      24-11-14    14               15
20      23-11-14    2   
20      24-11-14    2                2
30      24-11-14    10  
30      25-11-14    3                10
40      25-11-14    2   
10      29-11-14    5                14
20      30-11-14    10               2
10      30-11-14    15               5
10      01-12-14    10               15
```

I know I can do it with lag but is there a way without using lag. If it is can someone suggests.Thanks!!!

Comment: CAn you show how you do it with lag?

Comment: I have not this type question but other other one and its simple you partition by and order by what exactly you want.

Comment: Why would you want to do this without `LAG`? It's possible (for each record take all previous records and from these the most recent), but why would you want to make it so complicated?

Comment: Its what my senior want...I don't know can you tell me the way

Comment: So they ask you to purposely write a query that is slower and worse to read? Tell them that makes no sense. As to explaining the way, well, I just did: "for each record take all previous records and from these the most recent". This is how you get the previous record, which you could much more easily achieve with `LAG`.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand :( can you please elaborate

Comment: Yes, I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query without the most recent count is easy:

```
select 
  product_id,
  trunc(sale_date) as sale_date,
  sum(quantity) as currentday_count
from sales
group by trunc(sale_date), product_id
order by trunc(sale_date), product_id;
```

And to get the previous value would be simple and fast with `LAG`:

```
select 
  product_id,
  sale_date,
  currentday_count,
  lag(currentday_count) over (partition by product_id order by sale_date) as prevday_count
from
(
  select 
    product_id,
    trunc(sale_date) as sale_date,
    sum(quantity) as currentday_count
  from sales
  group by trunc(sale_date), product_id
)
order by sale_date, product_id;
```

But you have been asked not to make use of `LAG`, but write a slower, more complicated query. You would have to access the same intermediate result (the daily sales) more than once, so you would use a `WITH` clause and get the previous sales in a correlated subquery:

```
with daily_sales as
(
  select 
    product_id,
    trunc(sale_date) as sale_date,
    sum(quantity) as currentday_count
  from sales
  group by trunc(sale_date), product_id
)
select 
  product_id,
  sale_date,
  currentday_count,
  (
    select max(currentday_count) keep (dense_rank last order by sale_date)
    from daily_sales older
    where older.product_id = daily_sales.product_id
    and older.sale_date < daily_sales.sale_date
  ) as prevday_count
from daily_sales
order by sale_date, product_id;
```

This still makes use of an analytic function (`KEEP LAST`). Without it, the query would get even more complicated and probably slowed down.